# R/zoo: handle non-unique index entries but not lose data?

Tags: r, zoo

I've a csv file of data points (e.g. financial ticks, experiment recordings, etc.), and my data has duplicate timestamps. Here is code demonstrating the problem:

```
library(zoo);library(xts)

csv="2011-11-01,50
2011-11-02,49
2011-11-02,48
2011-11-03,47
2011-11-03,46
2011-11-03,45
2011-11-04,44
2011-11-04,43
2011-11-04,42
2011-11-04,41
"

z1=read.zoo(textConnection(csv),sep=',')
w1=to.weekly(z1)
ep=endpoints(z1,"weeks",1)
w1$Volume=period.apply(z1,ep,length)

z2=read.zoo(textConnection(csv),sep=',',aggregate=T)
w2=to.weekly(z2)
ep=endpoints(z2,"weeks",1)
w2$Volume=period.apply(z2,ep,length)
```

vignette('zoo-faq'), entry 1, tells me aggregate=T gets rid of zoo's annoying warning message. But then the results change:

```
> w1
           z1.Open z1.High z1.Low z1.Close Volume
2011-11-04      50      50     41       41     10
> w2
           z2.Open z2.High z2.Low z2.Close Volume
2011-11-04      50      50   42.5     42.5      4
```

Is there another way to get rid of the warning message but still get the same results as w1? (Yes, I know about suppressWarnings(), which is what I was using before, but I hate the idea.)
(I was wondering about passing a custom aggregate function to read.zoo that would return OHLCV data for each day... but couldn't even work out if that was even possible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a simple variant on Dirk's suggestion, this should work

```
z0 = read.csv( textConnection(csv), sep=',', header=FALSE )
z1 = zoo( z0$V2, as.Date(z0$V1) + (1:nrow(z0))*10^-10 )
```

Comment: That is a) too crude as you keep adding where you do not need to and b) 1e-10 is too small, so POSIXct still sees it as equivalent.

Comment: @Dirk,  But it does seem to work as does `to.weekly(z1)`.  It could also be expressed like this:  `z1 <- read.zoo(text = csv, sep = ",", FUN = function(x) as.Date(x) + seq_along(x) / 10^10)`

Comment: Seems like I misread---these are `Date` not `POSIXct`. I am only ever concerned with identical milliseconds, and there are adding a small epsilon (around 1e-7) does help.  Dates, represented as integers, must flip to double where 1e-10 can indeed be represented.

Comment: `z2=zoo(z0$V2,as.POSIXct(z0$V1)+(1:nrow(z0)*3.0e-7))` or `z2=read.zoo(textConnection(csv),sep=',',FUN = function(x) as.POSIXct(x) + seq_along(x)*3e-7)` work nicely (less then 3.0e-7 still gave the zoo warning). The potential issues, if importing a high number of rows in one go, have been noted.

Comment: I still consider that method to be way too "dirty" because of the rather bad offset.  See another edit to my answer for an example for Date types.

Answer (score 4):

You need a function to pad the time stamps with an "epsilon" increment to make them 
different.

I have also written one or two Rcpp-based functions to do that. Times are after all most often POSIXct which is really a float (after you do `as.numeric`), so just loop over the time stamps, and on equality to the previous one keep adding a small delta of 1.0e-7 which is smaller than what POSIXct itself can represent. Reset the cumulative delta each time you have an actual break.

*Edit:* Try  the `make.index.unique()` and `make.time.unique()` functions in the xts package:

```
R> sametime <- rep(Sys.time(), 3)
R> xts(1:3, order.by=make.time.unique(sametime))
                           [,1]
2011-12-20 06:52:37.547299    1
2011-12-20 06:52:37.547300    2
2011-12-20 06:52:37.547301    3
R>
```

*Edit 2:*  Here is another example for `Date` indexed objects:

```
R> samedate <- rep(Sys.Date(), 5)   # identical dates
R> xts(1:5, order.by=make.time.unique(as.POSIXct(samedate)))
                           [,1]
2011-12-19 18:00:00.000000    1
2011-12-19 18:00:00.000000    2
2011-12-19 18:00:00.000001    3
2011-12-19 18:00:00.000002    4
2011-12-19 18:00:00.000003    5
R> xts(1:5, order.by=as.Date(make.index.unique(as.POSIXct(samedate))))
           [,1]
2011-12-20    1
2011-12-20    2
2011-12-20    3
2011-12-20    4
2011-12-20    5
R>
```

The first solution switches to POSIXct, which ends up at six hours before midnight as GMT minus six hours is my local timezone.  The second example uses a dual conversion away, and back to `Date` --- which has then been made unique.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. How do you fit that in with read.zoo? I just tried `myglobal<<-0;z3=read.zoo(textConnection(csv),sep=',',FUN=function(v){myglobal<<-(myglobal+1);as.POSIXct(v)+myglobal;})` but _all_ my timestamps only get 1 second added. (+1 would eventually be +1.0e-7, but this way was clearer while testing.)

Comment: I modify the POSIXct column after reading and before creating the xts or zoo object, hence I don't use `read.zoo`.

Comment: See my edit to my answer: `make.time.unique()` from xts helps.

Comment: Hello @Dirk I get this when I try your code: Error in UseMethod("make.index.unique") : 
  no applicable method for 'make.index.unique' applied to an object of class "c('POSIXct', 'POSIXt')"
(I'm on version 2.13.1 of xts and zoo; would that be related?)

Comment: I just checked my (not current) SVN checkout of XTS, and that function has been added in January 2011, and there have multiple xts releases since then. What version are you running?