# R: time series with duplicate time index entries

Tags: r, indexing, unique

I am a n00b at R and a n00b at stack overflow (just joined), so forgive me if I have failed to use markup (which I don't know) or missed something in the readme.

If you don't mind, I will go through my full problem here as perhaps you might be kind enough to shed some insight into how I should best go about this!

Stage 1
Construction of individual time-series objects for each TS1 Please find a data example below. Essentially, I am loading a csv file with multiple, irregular time-series in it (example TS1, TS2) below, so in an ideal world, I would split these into individual, irregular time-series objects (e.g. zoo?), so TS1, TS2, ... this problem was discussed here ([R/zoo: handle non-unique index entries but not lose data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570716/r-zoo-handle-non-unique-index-entries-but-not-lose-data/25812246#25812246)) but I have tried repeatedly to use this approach, and failed.

```
 Date TS Data 
 21/05/2014 TS1 0.95  
 17/04/2014 TS1 1.02   
 27/03/2014 TS1 0.90   
 30/01/2014 TS1 0.80   
 12/12/2013 TS1 0.70  
 18/09/2013 TS1 0.67  
 01/11/2012 TS1 0.71  
 01/11/2012 TS1 0.70  
 21/05/2014 TS2 0.47  
 20/05/2014 TS2 0.51  
 16/05/2014 TS2 0.49  
 15/05/2014 TS2 0.55  
 10/05/2014 TS2 0.63  
 07/05/2014 TS2 0.77
```

as can be seen, the problem arises due to duplicate date index of `01/11/2012` for TS1 which causes `read.zoo` not to create my split data object.

Stage 2
What I would then like to do is, on every irregular date, add all the data as of that date together. Since all the time-series are irregular, and with different regularity, I would like to use the prior value for a `TS`. E.g. for `21/05/2014`, this calculation in the example is straightforward as both TS1 and 2 have an entry, so the answer would be `0.47 + 0.95`. But for `20/05`, only `TS2` has an entry, so the value for `TS1` that should be used is the most recent one as of that date, i.e. the `17/04/2014` value of `1.02`, so the calculation for `20/05/2014` should be `0.51 + 1.02`. It could be that the simplest way of achieving this might be to convert each TS into a daily value, such that the previous value is used until a new data point? but this is wasteful/unnecessary for stage 3 below.

Stage 3
Having created this aggregated data sum of all the TS', I want to do a polynomial curve-fit. I also want to differentiate this curve-fit to find the rate-of-change as of today's date predicated by this fitted curve.

Any help would be much appreciated! I feel that repeatedly hitting my head against a wall would be more fun than doing anything more at this stage!!

Thanks

Updated: I now have code as follows thanks to Grothendieck.

```
library(scales)  
library(zoo)  
library(ggplot2)  

f <- function (z) {  
zz <- read.zoo(z, header = TRUE, split = 2, format = "%d/%m/%Y", aggregate = mean);  
z.fill <- na.locf(zz);  
z.fill <- (z.fill >= 0.5) * z.fill;  
z.fill <- na.fill(z.fill,0);  
zfill.mat = matrix(z.fill, NROW(z.fill));  
z.sum <- rowSums(zfill.mat);  
zsum <- zoo(z.sum,time(z.fill));  
return(zsum);  
}  

DF <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE);  
DF.S <- split(DF[-2], DF[[2]]);  
user <- DF[1,2];  
Ret <- lapply(DF.S,  f);
```

I a remaining problem:
  Ret contains a list of a data frame.  I can access this by typing Ret$user, but since user varies, I need to make this dynamic.  I have tried to construct a dynamic expression e.g.:
    x <- paste("Ret$'",user,"'",sep = "");
    plot(x)

but could not get this to evaluate.

Comment: I've come across this a couple times, an easy option is to read.table, then aggregate all duplicate date entries in whatever way you please, then convert to zoo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read.zoo` has an `aggregate=` argument which takes a function that is used to aggregate the values at duplicate times in the same series.  Here we take the `mean` of duplicate days within series but you could use `sum` or any other function. (If the data were coming from a file we would replace `text = Lines` argument in `read.zoo` with something like `"myfile.dat"`.) Then we use `na.locf` to fill in the NAs, sum the rows and we use `na.omit` to drop any leading NAs giving `zsum`.  Next we compute a regularly spaced time grid `g` and a spline function `splfun` evaluating that function and its derivative on the grid which, after converting back to zoo, give `zspl` and `zder`.  Finally we plot them.

```
Lines <- "Date TS Data 
 21/05/2014 TS1 0.95  
 17/04/2014 TS1 1.02   
 27/03/2014 TS1 0.90   
 30/01/2014 TS1 0.80   
 12/12/2013 TS1 0.70  
 18/09/2013 TS1 0.67  
 01/11/2012 TS1 0.71  
 01/11/2012 TS1 0.70  
 21/05/2014 TS2 0.47  
 20/05/2014 TS2 0.51  
 16/05/2014 TS2 0.49  
 15/05/2014 TS2 0.55  
 10/05/2014 TS2 0.63  
 07/05/2014 TS2 0.77"

library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, split = 2, format = "%d/%m/%Y",
       aggregate = mean)
zsum <- na.omit(zoo(rowSums(na.locf(z)), time(z)))

g <- seq(start(zsum), end(zsum), "day")
splfun <- splinefun(time(zsum), coredata(zsum))
zspl <- zoo(splfun(g), g)
zder <- zoo(splfun(g, deriv = 1), g)

plot(merge(zspl, zder))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much.  Just for anyone else who looks at this trying to solve a similar problem, I wanted to use a zero where a TS had an NA, rather than omit.  To do this, I modified your zsum as follows:    zsum <- zoo(rowSums(na.fill(na.locf(z),0)), time(z)).  One more thing that I now need to do is edit each TS so that if TS < 0.5, TS = 0.

Comment: Try: `(TS > 0.5) * TS`

Comment: Thank you again.  Just to clarify for other n00bs like me, (TS > 0.5) is a condition so if its true, then the () is 1, and 1*TS = TS.  Otherwise, if TS <= 0.5, the () are false, ie. 0, and 0*TS = 0.

Comment: One more question: what G. Grothendieck has given me so far is brilliant, but I am stumped on the next bit.  What I actually have is a group of these TS and Data by another column i.e. my data format is of the form: Date,User,TS,Data, not just Date, TS, Data.  What I want to do is loop over users doing the analysis above for each user (split on user?). Then I want to be able to access the spline/plots for each user, either by index number, or by user name.  Any further help on this is much appreciated; I have googled but not found the answer.

Comment: If `User` is the second column then: `DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE); lapply(split(DF[-2], DF[[2]]), f)` where `f` is a function to process a single user based on the answer above.   Note that `read.zoo` can read data.frames too.

Comment: Great! took me a little while to figure out but that works.  I don't quite understand the DF[-2] here.  You have been an enormous help.

Comment: `DF` without column 2.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm now stuck again: for some users, there is only one Time-series, and thus rowSums fails with the error " 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions".  I guess to get around this, I would need to use an if statement i.e. if dimensions of DF.S array element for current user are 1, then use the Data value, otherwise sum across array elements?

Comment: Some functions take the argument `drop=FALSE`.  Alternately, set the dimensions: `dim(obj) <- c(NROW(obj), NCOL(obj))`

Comment: Are you suggesting adding a column? i.e. dim(obj) <- c(NROW(obj), NCOL(obj) + 1), and then converting the new empty rows into 0s?  I also wondered whether apply might be usable instead of rowSums?

Comment: I thought your problem is that you have a vector and want it to be a single column object.  That was likely caused either by not using `drop=FALSE` (as the default is to drop dimensions in that case) or if it arose in some other context then you can reshape it using `dim`.

Comment: Ah, no, I think my problem is that I sometimes have a single column object (i.e., one TS with data varying over multiple dates (rows), when rowSums needs at least two TS to sum across rows.  Therefore, rowSums fails because it says I need a 2+ dimensional array to sum the columns off.  In the instances where I have a single column, I'd just like to use that columns value (equivalent to adding a zero to that column's value).  Otherwise, rowSums seems to work admirably.

Comment: You can reshape your object to make it 2d.  This works if `x` is a vector or matrix: `x <- 1:5; rowSums(matrix(x, NROW(x)))`

Comment: @Grothendieck thanks for your help, this works. I am now stuck again. Essentially, I'm trying to return the results for each User from f. I've modified my original question above to reflect this. What is happening is that I get returned a List of dataframes into Ret, i.e. I can reference the zsum dataframe that I want by doing Ret$User, but I am struggling to construct this quantity automatically e.g. using paste("Ret$'",user,"'",sep=""). Ideally what I would like to do is combine the output results for each User into a new data frame/table, and then dump to csv.